# Pronunciation of "Priapus"

Tags: classical-latin, pronunciation, names

How is the name *Priapus* pronounced in Classical Latin? I don't know if the primary stress is on the first syllable (Pri) or the penultimate (ap).

Answer (score 5):

The *a* of *Priāpus* is [long](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3DPriapus1), which means that by Latin stress rules, the stress is on the penult.